# Why i'm getting value error at the time of train_test_split method in linear regression

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, prediction, valueerror

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zh6LC.png)

i'm performing some tests at that time i'm getting value error while spliting

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming because your X and Y don't have the same length (which is what train_test_split requires), i.e., X.shape[0] != Y.shape[0]. 
try this:

```
>>> X.shape

>>> Y.shape
```

And then to fix this:

- You have to remove the extra list from inside of np.array() when
  defining X or remove the extra dimension afterwards with the
  following command: X = X.reshape(X.shape[1:]).
- And then Transpose X by running X = X.transpose() to get equal number
  of samples in X and Y.